# How to Return Active Query Result as One-Dimensional Array in Codeigniter?

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

Every time, I query data from database table, it returns result as multi-dimensional array, so I have to do nested for-loop in view in order to get an actual data that I want. I don't want it to be like that because it is not necessary to a nested loop every time for my case. Is there any way that I can get only one dimensional array returned that points to actual data? Thanks.

Here's my model:

```
    public function get_contact_info($userid){
        $res = $this->db->get_where('contact_info',array('userid'=>$userid));
        return $res->result_array();
    }
```

Here's my controller:

```
   $userid = $this->session->userdata('userid');

   $this->load->model('User','user');
   $res = $this->user->get_contact_info($userid);

    var_dump($res);
```

Output:

```
   C:\wamp64\www\findjob.com\application\controllers\Job.php:64:
    array (size=2)
      0 => 
        array (size=6)
          'contact_id' => string '1' (length=1)
          'name' => string 'Jonh' (length=4)
          'title' => string 'Mr.' (length=3)
          'phone' => string '01932834784' (length=11)
          'email' => string 'Jonh@gmail.com' (length=14)
          'userid' => string '1' (length=1)
      1 => 
        array (size=6)
          'contact_id' => string '2' (length=1)
          'name' => string 'Smith' (length=5)
          'title' => string 'Mr.' (length=3)
          'phone' => string '0293893' (length=7)
          'email' => string 'smith@yahoo.com' (length=15)
          'userid' => string '1' (length=1)
```

Comment: Please explain how it would be possible to return 2 result rows each with multiple column data as a single dimensional array?? Oh please, please... tell me, please

Comment: @RiggsFolly, i did not quite get it, that's my question. Exactly, I don't want my array to be preceded with index 0 and 1.

Comment: And my point! How would you return 2 or more rows ___any other way___

Comment: @RiggsFolly, another way is to return result as object example. `return $res->result();`. Sorry, if it does not hit your point.

Comment: Yes, but that I believe will return an array of objects, not really much different to an array of arrays

Comment: @RiggsFolly, yes certainly, thus, I wondered how come it was like this.

Comment: Back to my original statement! _How else are you going to return 2 or more rows of data, if not in an array or some kind of collection that requires processing with a loop of some kind_

Comment: yes no way to go without looping for kind of collection like array. is it possible to avoid nested loop?

Comment: Show an example of what you are trying to avoid. A single foreach shoudl be enough to process this example

Comment: foreach($job as $k=>$v):

Comment: Well if you want to process each field individually, then you are always going to be in nested loop territory

Comment: @RiggsFolly, this is I'm trying to avoid `<?php foreach($job as $k=>$v):?><?php if(is_array($v)): foreach ($v as $kk => $vv):?>`. I had to loop one time, then I had to check if the value is still an array, then I had to loop it again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since my model return result as an array of multiple rows and columns, there is no way to get data without looping. For instance, my loop as

```
    foreach($jobs as $key => $value){
      $value['column_name'];
    }
```

Because `$value` here is another array containing another key and value of itself, and it is the value that I need to get. Thus, from inside the loop, I used `$value['column_name']` to access the value of each column that I need.

By this way, I can avoid using nested foreach loop, a loop through array `$value`. Thanks.